# Actions on Google oAuth Sign In fails when returning to application

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

I'm creating a voice application in Action on Google with the Actions SDK. It contains the Sign In helper (oAuth with Authorization Code).

When asking for a sign in the user has a Yes/No option. Both options are redirected to a new intent with the name actions.intent.SIGN_IN

The intent triggering the Sign In process:

```js
app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', async (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To access your account'));
});
```

The intent that is triggered after the sign in process:

```js
app.intent('actions.intent.SIGN_IN', (conv, input, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    conv.ask(`Great, thanks for signing in! What do you want to do next?`);
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`);
  }
});
```

When starting the sign in process and answering 'No' to the question if you want to connect your account, the user goes to the actions.intent.SIGN_IN intent and gets the message that data can't be saved.

When answering 'Yes' the authorization flow is started and when logging in I have an access token in my request JSON. But then my app crashes with the following error:

> Error: Input text not set.

I have compared both the JSON requests and it seems that when returning from logging in there is no Raw Input in the request.

Request when choosing No at Sign In:

```
"inputs": [{
    "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
    "rawInputs": [{
        "inputType": "TOUCH",
        "query": "Nee"
    }],
    "arguments": [{
            "name": "SIGN_IN",
            "extension": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValue",
                "status": "CANCELLED"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "rawText": "Nee",
            "textValue": "Nee"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Request when choosing Yes at Sign In:

```
"inputs": [{
    "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
    "rawInputs": [{
        "inputType": "VOICE"
    }],
    "arguments": [{
            "name": "SIGN_IN",
            "extension": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValue",
                "status": "OK"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "text"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Is the app crashing at some point in your code? If so, can you show the full error message and stack trace and the code where the error is occurring? Or is this happening in a library?

Comment: Google Assistant is finishing with a status 500. The whole error in the Firebase Functions log is:
`Error: Input text not set.
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:101:45)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)`

Comment: My guess is that the actions-on-google library expects a query inside rawInput, and the request doesn't have that when returning to the application after completing the authorization.